# Alert me Windows Phone Push Notifications In Azure Mobile Service

Tags: push-notification, azure-mobile-services, mpns

Basically my understanding of push notifications is that they can change tiles and display a message to the user when the app is closed.

What I would like to know is if its the right way to go as the main control method in a turn based mobile game? For example the specific situation im wondering about is if the user has the application open and they make their move which gets sent off to my service could the application then sit and  listen for the push notification reply and update the ui/continue with the users turn? obviously if the user moved away it should still do the sort of notification mentioned first that updates tiles/ displays a message but if the apps open it should just use a value in the notification and the user should never know it was a notification, just see the other players move and continue with theirs?

thank you

John Harris

Answer (score 2):

> Toast notifications are ignored if your app is already running, unless you register for the ShellToastNotificationReceived event. Your app can then decide how it wants to respond to the toast notification.

As you can see from this quote,  if the app is open, it can choose to recieve toast notifications and decide how to handle them.

When the app is running you can also  receive raw notifications, which can contain more data than toast notifications.

Comment: Thanks for your response so is it the correct way to go? I also asked a similar question on msdn forums and they have all suggested that because toasts cant be guaranteed it would not be whats your opinion?